# IF statement with AND statement: If date field is NULL and today's date is 5 days before due date

Tags: formula-field, if

I'm not getting any errors but I'm not getting the results that I'm looking for. The field is empty if the proposal date is empty and if today's date is 5 days before the proposal due date is. The following formula (the first part of the formula) is supposed to populate the formula field with a text if the proposal due date is in 5 days from today.

I tried to use "AND" in case the Proposal date field is not populated and if today's date is 5 days before the due date.

```
IF( AND(Proposal_Date__c = NULL,Proposal_Due_Date__c = TODAY()+5), "Proposal is due SOON", 
IF( Proposal_Date__c = Proposal_Due_Date__c - 5, "Proposal Due in 5 Days", 
IF( Proposal_Date__c = Proposal_Due_Date__c - 4, "Proposal Due in 4 Days", 
IF( Proposal_Date__c = Proposal_Due_Date__c - 3, "Proposal Due in 3 Days", 
IF( Proposal_Date__c = Proposal_Due_Date__c - 2, "Proposal Due in 2 Days", 
IF( Proposal_Date__c = Proposal_Due_Date__c - 1, "Proposal Due in 1 Day", 
IF( Proposal_Date__c = Proposal_Due_Date__c, "Proposal Due Today", 
IF( Proposal_Date__c >= Proposal_Due_Date__c, "Proposal is Past Due",NULL))))))))
```

Comment: How `Proposal_Date__c` and = `Proposal_Due_Date__c` are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something closer to this:

```
IF(
 AND(
  ISBLANK(Proposal_Date__c),
  Proposal_Due_Date__c = Today() + 5
 ),
 "Propsal is due SOON",
 IF(
  Proposal_Due_Date__c - Proposal_Date__c = 0,
  "Propsal is due Today",
  IF(
   Proposal_Due_Date__c - Proposal_Date__c < 0,
   "Propsal is PAST DUE",
   IF(
    Proposal_Due_Date__c - Proposal_Date__c > 5,
    "<default text or blank>",
    "Proposal Due in " & Proposal_Due_Date__c - Proposal_Date__c & " days"
   ) 
  )
 )
)
```

At the very least, this will reduce the number of if statements in your formula.

**Be Advised:**

This might help answer your question as it was asked, but I fear that your original formula may not solve your business use case.

My guess is the proposal date represents when the proposal was submitted, performed or otherwise completed. **If this is true, it drastically changes the formula.** If it's not true, than I question the use case.